# SMS saving to SD

Tags: sms, sd-card, mms

Is there any way of saving simple SMS mixed with MMS messages to an SD card prior to running a full factory reset? I got a Sony Z3 that refuses to send pic messages other than when I'm hooked to WiFi - Voda can't find or fix the issue and they suggest a full factory reset but I don't want to lose all the messages

Answer (score 1):

I use [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore), it works great! And it has a cloud plugin for saving messages to Google Drive and Dropbox.
Once installed, go to the app settings, and choose your SD card as backup folder.